# Simple String-sending client server handler Java

Tags: java, http-post, client-server

I would like to programme a very simple Server-Client pair in Java, meaning that I have a server, available under localhost/port showing Strings. So if I open the website, it shows something like:

```
Hello World
Hi
How are you?
```

The clients are all using the same programme, but they all see exactly the same page. Every client can append the current page by several lines when they want.

I tried to research a lot, but haven't found a good example for it.

At the moment, my programmes look like that:
Server:

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class DomServer {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // don't need to specify a hostname, it will be the current machine
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(7777);
        System.out.println("ServerSocket awaiting connections...");
        Socket socket = ss.accept(); // blocking call, this will wait until a connection is attempted on this port.
        System.out.println("Connection from " + socket + "!");

        // get the input stream from the connected socket
        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
        // create a DataInputStream so we can read data from it.
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

        // read the message from the socket
        String message = dataInputStream.readUTF();
        System.out.println("The message sent from the socket was: " + message);

        System.out.println("Closing sockets.");
        //ss.close();
        //socket.close();
    }
}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class DomClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // need host and port, we want to connect to the ServerSocket at port 7777
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 7777);
        System.out.println("Connected!");

        // get the output stream from the socket.
        OutputStream outputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
        // create a data output stream from the output stream so we can send data
        // through it
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(outputStream);

        System.out.println("Sending string to the ServerSocket");

        // write the message we want to send
        boolean terminate = false;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
         
        while(!terminate) {
            String text = reader.readLine();
            if(text.equals("end")) {
                terminate = true;
            }
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(text);
            dataOutputStream.flush(); // send the message
            
        }
        dataOutputStream.close(); // close the output stream when we're done.

        System.out.println("Closing socket and terminating program.");
        socket.close();
    }
}
```

Its a modified copy of that one: https://gist.github.com/chatton/8955d2f96f58f6082bde14e7c33f69a6

At the moment, I am suffering from the problem that the connection closes itself when I type in a third line. I am getting java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe (Write failed).
Moreover, I do not have an idea on how to solve the problem with the expendable string website.

Is there somebody having programmed something similar?

Comment: You should really improve your Google research skills and look for a better tutorial. E.g. google for "java socket client server example" and the [first hit](https://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/java-socket-server-examples-tcp-ip) seems to be better suited. On the server side the `accept()` is usually inside a loop. And `DataOutputStream` and `DataInputStream` are the wrong classes for a simple string protocol. You should use a Reader/Writer instead like a `InputStreamReader` wrapped by a `BufferedReader`.

Comment: Thank you vanje! I will have a look for it